# Delete all user folders except "AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data*" and '\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Edge\User Data*"

Tags: powershell

I'm looking to delete all user folders except for the Chrome and Edge user data with powershell
Can anyone help me build a script?

Here is what I already tried (didn't delete anything)

```
(Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\\Users' -Directory -Filter 'AppData') -NotLike '*\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome*' -NotLike '*\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\Edge*' | Remove-Item -Recurse -Force

Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\\Users' -Directory -Filter 'AppData' | Where-Object {$_.FullName -NotLike '_*\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome*' -and $.FullName -NotLike '*\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\Edge*'} | Remove-Item -Recurse

$toKeep = "*\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome*", "*\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\Edge*"
gci 'C:\\Users' -Recurse | ? { !$_.PSIsContainer } | ? { $toKeep -notcontains $_.Name } | remove-item -Force
```

Answer (score 0):

- A **fundamental problem** with your attempt is your **use of `\\` in a mistaken attempt to escape verbatim `\` characters**:

  - `\` (a backslash) has *no* special meaning in PowerShell, so there's **never a need to use `\\` in file-system paths in PowerShell**
    (PowerShell's [escape character](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Special_Characters) - where needed - is `` ` ``, the so-called *backtick*).
- `AppData` directories are *hidden* directories; in order for [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem) to include them, you must use the `-Force` switch.
- However, since the `AppData` folders aren't *immediate* subdirectories of `C:\Users`, `Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Users' -Directory -Filter 'AppData'` wouldn't find them even with `-Force`.

---

- You can use `Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Users\*\AppData -Force` in a first step to retrieve the `AppData` directories across all users and use a *nested* `Get-ChildItem` call with `-Recurse` in order to enumerate their respective content recursively.
- You can then filter the resulting items by their full paths to exclude the subdirectory trees of interest, using [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object) with [wildcard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Wildcards) patterns and the [`-notlike`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-notlike) operator, as in your second attempt.

```bash
#requires -RunAsAdministrator
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Users\*\AppData -Force |
  Get-ChildItem -Force -Recurse |
  Where-Object { 
    $_.FullName -notlike '*\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome*' -and
    $_.FullName -notlike  '*\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Edge*'
  } |
  Remove-Item -Recurse -WhatIf
```

<sup>Note: The [**`-WhatIf`** common parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters#-whatif) in the command above ***previews* the operation**. Remove `-WhatIf` and re-execute once you're sure the operation will do what you want.</sup>

Comment: Also something like `(dir) -notlike '*chrome*'` will turn the objects to strings.